# ViewPager animatin in fragmentTransaction

Tags: android

I'm trying to obtain an ViewPager like animation using fragmentManager.
You can see the animation here: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

I tryed to apply a CustomAnimation to the transaction using an animation like that:

```
    <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:valueFrom="-100"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:duration="@integer/slide_in_left_animation_duration" />
```

But this animation is significantly different from what I'm looking for.
Is there a way to do that? Or I have to use a ViewPager? (I don't think that ViewPager is the right solution.. in fact my app have to change the fragment depending on the user input, I can't fill an ArrayList a priori)

Answer (score 1):

This library provides an easy way to set viewPager page change animations and has quite many types implemented. It's also easy to use, see it's example application and documentation.

https://github.com/ToxicBakery/ViewPagerTransforms

Comment: It's pretty awesome to see my own library as a suggested answer.